# Reference for auto-duality of nearly ordinary deformations associated to Hida families

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, hida-theory

suppose we have a $p$-stabilized newform $f$ of classical level $\Gamma_0(p)$; then there is a unique ordinary deformation into a Hida family $\mathbf{f}$ defined over a finite flat extension $R/\Lambda$, and a corresponding representation $\rho: G_{\mathbb{Q}}\to \text{GL}_2(\text{Frac}(R))$ on a big vector space $\mathbb{V}$. Under some mild conditions, there exists a free rank-two $R$-lattice $\mathbb{T}\subset \mathbb{V}$.

I believe there should be some kind of autoduality for $\mathbb{V}$, and maybe $\mathbb{T}$ as well, in the form of a perfect pairing
$$
\mathbb{T} \times \mathbb{T} \to R(1)
$$
or similar, which is equivariant. Does anyone have a reference where this kind of thing is spelled out?

Comment: My entry point would be Section 7 of Kings, Loeffler, Zerbes, “Rankin-Eisenstein classes and explicit reciprocity laws” (https://arxiv.org/abs/1503.02888) and references therein, but that may not be optimal. I merely happened to study that paper not too long ago.

Comment: theorem 7.2.3(v) is very close to what I want, but it doesn't say anything about the Galois action!

Comment: Oops, you’re right (I thought they talked about the Galois action, though…). Maybe in the Ohta paper that they cite, then?

Comment: found it in a different ohta paper!

Comment: @xir If you put together parts (iii), (iv), and (v) of the theorem from KLZ, then the Galois action drops out; but it isn't literally $R(1)$ that it lands in, it is $R(1 + \mathbf{k})$, where $\mathbf{k}$ is the canonical character $\mathbf{Z}_p^\times \to R^\times$ which specialises to $x \mapsto x^k$ at a weight $k$ point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Section 1.6 in Fukaya-Kato](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Esharifi/sharificonj.pdf) spells it out very nicely; the same material appeared earlier in section 4.1 of Ohta's *On the $p$-adic Eichler-Shimura isomorphism for $\Lambda$-adic cusp forms*.